# Pandas DF Average All Years by Month and Day

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, average, days

I have data that looks like this in a df called "aodata" (25627,4)

```
       Year  Month Day  Index
0      1950      1   1 -2.511
1      1950      1   2 -1.505
2      1950      1   3 -1.173
3      1950      1   4 -1.251
4      1950      1   5 -0.126
...    ...  ..    ...
25622  2020      2  25  1.836
25623  2020      2  26  1.724
25624  2020      2  27  2.151
25625  2020      2  28  1.848
25626  2020      2  29  1.741
```

And i need to find the long-term daily average (from all years) of the "Index" column so that my output looks like this for a specific month like February (month ==2):

```
Month Day AvgIndex
2   1   -5.43
2   2   -5.29
2   3   -4.15
... ... ...
2   29   3.46
```

I have tried different combinations of

```
cmao_mean = aodata[(aodata.Month == month)&(aodata.Day)].Index.mean() #gives a single number of the average of all the days in the month.
```

And, I have tried to do this with a for loop like this:

```
days = list(range(1,29))
for x in days:
     dmao = aodata[(aodata.Month == month)&(aodata.Day)].Index.mean(x)
```

This gives me an error like this:

```
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I'm new to Python but I'm learning. Thank you for any help with this!

Comment: Does `aodata.groupby(['Month','Day']).mean()` give you what you want?

Comment: Yeah, almost works if I do this - aodata.groupby(['Month','Day']).Index.mean() ...this gives me the daily average by month for all months but is there a way to calculate it for just month ==2 or take the output for just month ==2?

Comment: Sure, just filter it like normal: `aodata[aodata.Month==2].groupby...`

Comment: perfect, filter then groupby!  thank you for your time.